# Как доказать, что NAT строгий?

Tags: nat, p2p, провайдер

Есть некий провайдер. Собственно скачивание работает на заявленной скорости (100 МБит/с), но входящие соединения режутся. Торрент-клиент ничего не раздаёт, только скачивает BitTorrent Sync передавать что-то позволяет, но на скорости менее 300 Кбит/с. Если кинуть порт, который показывается для соединения с *sync*-ом (показывается файерволлом на другом компьютере в другой сети) в онлайн-сканер портов, то показывается, что порт закрыт.

Насколько я понимаю, это означает использование провайдером строгого NAT'а и может быть исправлено только на стороне провайдера.

Дело не в скорости передачи/приёма, а в направлении соединения - по исходящему можно скачивать и передавать на 100 МБит/с, а с входящими что-то идёт не так. Проверка спидтестом показывает примерно одинаковые скорости приёма и передачи.

Как можно доказать провайдеру, что проблема на его стороне?
Есть ли какие-то онлайн-сервисы (типа спидтеста), для проверки через которые не требуется компьютер, подключенный к другой сети?

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое строгий нат. Но похоже Вы просто за двойным натом и "проблему" можно решить, просто заказав себе внешний реальный айпи

Comment: Или я чего-то не понимаю, или это не баг, а фича большинства провайдеров, просто потому что IPv4 давно кончились

Comment: @andreymal, у другого провайдера (тоже при сером IP) этой проблемы нет. А в чём заключается фича и какая от неё польза?

Comment: @Qwertiy у другого провайдера может IPv4 просто ещё не успели кончиться :)

Comment: @Qwertiy фича в том, что через NAT на один айпишник можно повесить много пользователей и таким образом можно экономить эти самые айпишники. И входящие соединения тут не сделать уже никак. У жадных провайдеров подключение внешнего айпишника без всяких NAT — целая отдельная платная услуга, некоторые щедрые ещё раздают их по умолчанию, но, боюсь, это ненадолго)

Comment: Стоп, при сером IP? А это как так?

Comment: @KoVadim, т. е. не покупая белый IP, нельзя ничего раздавать через торрент? Мягко говоря, не впечатляет. Строгий нат - это когда только тот, с кем было открыто соединение, может по нему что-то слать (ну, приблизительно). Честно говоря, я и сам в этой теме почти не разбираюсь.

Comment: @andreymal, на один ip будут мапиться много ip, но ведь кроме ip есть порт. Для передачи нужно однозначное соответствие моего порта (а не ip) внешнему. т. е. надо просто переназначать порты.

Comment: "Строгий нат - это когда только тот, с кем было открыто соединение, может по нему что-то слать " - это любой нат. Конечно, некоторые наты можно "пробить", но это отдельная тема.

Comment: @andreymal, или динамический ip может быть белым? Но вроде нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy а как провайдеру определять, какому пользователю отдать этот порт? А если много пользователей захотят один и тот же порт?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, динамический IP может быть белым. У теле2 раньше были такие, но сейчас, похоже, они кончились и всех подключают через NAT :(

Comment: @KoVadim, в торренте происходит соединение моего клиента с трекером, трекер определяет, откуда к нему пришло солединение и этот ip с портом отдаёт другому клиенту для скачивания. Клиент коннектится по эти данным и... при открытом нате коннектится успешно и начинается передача, а при строгом - нет, поскольку соединения с ним я не устанавливал.

Comment: @andreymal, порт не должен совпадать у меня и у провайдера. Т. е. берём рандомный свободный порт порвайдера и ставим в соответствие тому, который я запросил.

Comment: @Qwertiy а если ваш сосед по подъезду поставит такой же торрент-клиент и возьмёт тот же самый «рандомный» свободный порт? :)